# latex command \greekbm

Tags: greek

I have a problem when compiling a latex file: undefined control sequence 
 \greekbm in a eqaution $$\greekbm{\tau}= Mgr$$. 
Does anyone know this command \greekbm and how to solve it?

best wishes,
Xin

Comment: Where did you hear of it and/or take this information from?

Comment: when latex compiles to the line of this equation,  it stops and shows this error

Comment: Sure. I'm asking where did you just come up with `\greekbm`? In order to help you, we need to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to text.stack....Hope it might be used to get the `greek` letters are in `bold font`, can you check with the tag `\boldsymbol` instead of `\greekbm`

Comment: @GongXin Apart from this question, please try to avoid `$$` for `display math`, hence it is a `plainTeX` tag, use `LaTeX` or `AMSTeX` tags like `\[..\]`, etc.

Comment: The author who wrote this code had left and I can not contact him. I guess that he wants to achieve the Greek letter in bold font, but I never find this command by Google, so I come here and hope some of you may know this command.

Comment: If any package in Latex has this command?

Comment: A search in the entire `latex` tree of TeX Live shows no match for `\greekbm`.

Answer (score 1):

Load the package `bm` and then define

```
\let\greekbm\bm
```

then `\greekbm` will work like `\bm`.  Alternatively of course you could edit the source file replacing `\greekbm` by `\bm`, still loading `bm` package to define `\bm`)

Comment: Fine, it works in the way.

Comment: I upvote your fine code considering your work.